# How can I pass large strings from one controller to another?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm attempting to send an HTML table from one controller to another, but because of the size of the table I'm getting HTTP 400 errors. I think the errors are coming from a lower level than the framework, as it's just a raw HTTP 400 error instead of an error with a stack, query, etc. like a normal exception does when debugging.

If I limit the size of the `DataTable` to a single row, it works just fine. But once I get past two or three rows the length of the query string gets long enough it starts throwing errors.

I tried passing the `DataTable` itself to `MailboxRulesResults` and then doing the conversion from DataTable to HTML table there using a `List<object>`, but the DataTable never made it to the function.

Is there a better way to do this or do I need to tweak a config somewhere?

Thanks in advance

```cs
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetMailboxRules(MailboxRulesModel mailbox)
        {
            string currentuser = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            using (DataTable results = Mail.GetMailboxRules(mailbox.EmailAddress, guid, currentuser))
            {
                List<string> return_list = new List<string>
                {
                    UtilityFunctions.ConvertDataTableToHTML(results, guid),
                    guid
                };
                return RedirectToAction("MailboxRulesResults", "Mail", new { data = return_list });
            }
        }
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult MailboxRulesResults(List<string> data)
        {
            ViewBag.TableHTML = data[0];
            ViewBag.Guid = data[1];
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You say 'query string', but your controller methods are all accepting `POST`s. Do you really mean query string? A query string will be appended onto the end of the request, and there is definitely a limit to the amount of data it can contain (limited by browser, and then by web server). If you are passing around larger pieces of data, `POST` is the correct way to do it, and you would pass it in via the payload of the request

Comment: When the view for `MailboxRulesResults` loads, the HTML table and the GUID are both in the URL. Looks something like `MailboxRulesResults?data=%3Ctable%20id%3D%2262ece1c8-e24a-43b0-959b-fcd00ae6def3%22%20class%3D%22table%20table-striped%20table-bordered%20table-hover%20...<snip>....&data=62ece1c8-e24a-43b0-959b-fcd00ae6def3`

Comment: Yeah... you don't want to do it that way. The data for the table should live in the view model for the view, and then you should bind the table to the data. Or, if you are using some sort of grid control, you would often make the data available on its own via a separate controller that returns json, and load it in independently of the rest of the page.

Comment: Ended up just having the original view send POST directly to MailboxRulesResults. Not sure why I bothered with the intermediate step in retrospect. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you just save that table as text file on server than get on next request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing my original view from

```html
<form asp-controller="Mail" asp-action="GetMailboxRules" method="post"
```

to

```html
<form asp-controller="Mail" asp-action="MailboxRulesResults" method="post"
```

and then having the `MailboxRulesResults` action handle everything.

```cs
 [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult MailboxRulesResults(MailboxRulesModel mailbox)
        {
            string currentuser = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            List<MailboxRulesModel> rules = Mail.GetMailboxRules(mailbox.EmailAddress, guid, currentuser);
            using (DataTable dt = UtilityFunctions.CreateDataTable(rules))
            {
                string html = UtilityFunctions.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt, guid);
                ViewBag.TableHTML = html;
                ViewBag.Guid = guid;
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following and save table as text file on server than get it on next request.

```
   private IHostingEnvironment _env;
       var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
           var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "table.txt");
 [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GetMailboxRules(MailboxRulesModel mailbox)
    {

        string currentuser = HttpContext.User.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        using (DataTable results = Mail.GetMailboxRules(mailbox.EmailAddress, guid, currentuser))
        {
            List<string> return_list = new List<string>
            {
                UtilityFunctions.ConvertDataTableToHTML(results, guid),
                guid
            };

          using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file))
          {
          foreach (string s in return_list)
           tw.WriteLine(s);  
          }
            return {Your action method without parameter}
        }
    }
```

**Then retrieve:**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult MailboxRulesResults(List<string> data)
    {

       using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {

            String line;
            // Read line by line
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);                

            }
        }
        ViewBag.TableHTML = line;
        ViewBag.Guid = data[1];
        return View();
    }
```